# Gmail Authentication in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, gmail

I am developing one application which needs the gmail user authentication? How can I integrate gmail login in my app? Any tutorials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/